# website with flexible width for different mobile devices

Tags: iphone, android, css, width

I have a site where it is targeted to be used on different mobile devices. How I can set my site to adjust its width according to the device width on iPhone android, etc.. using css and Java script

tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to html and adjust parameters.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

More info on how to use Safari and iOS specific HTML tagshttp://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/usingtheviewport/usingtheviewport.html

Comment: That's interesting, never knew that.

Comment: I put a new post in relation to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075522/issue-with-viewport-meta-tag

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like responsive design!
Have a look at some of the examples here: http://mediaqueri.es/, using media queries in their css to change the look of the site depending on browser width.